# how can I make a method of a class be const

Tags: c++

how is it right to write:

```
bool const f(...);
or bool f(...) const ;
or const bool f(...)  ;
```

I mean if there is a difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

1. `const bool f();` says its returning a const bool that won't ever change its value
2. `bool f() const;` says f is a const function that won't modify any variables in the class

In case 1, `const bool f();`, the returned bool has to be declared as a const and initialised on declaration or in the class's constructor.

```
const bool f() { return m_bool; }
```

where m_bool is declared as `const bool m_bool = false;`

In case 2, `bool f() const;`, the return value doesn't guarantee that it will never be changed but the function itself guarantees that it wont change any data members inside the class and it won't call any member function that isn't declared const. ([Some exceptions apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2h0ktk.aspx))

```
bool f() const { return m_bool; } // valid
bool f() const { m_bool = false; return m_bool; } // invalid, m_bool cannot be changed from a const function.
```

where m_bool can be declared as either `const bool m_bool = false;` or `bool m_bool;`

---

More information about const variables can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh.aspx) and more information about const functions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ke686zh.aspx).

Comment: -1 : `bool f() const` does not mean that the function won’t modify any variable in the class.

Comment: @qdii You're wrong. `A constant member function cannot modify any data members or call any member functions that aren't constant.` [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ke686zh.aspx)

Comment: It can modify `mutable` data members, it can also modify whatever it wants if a `const-cast` is used on `this`. So, no, writing `const` doesn’t guarantee that no member will be modified.

Comment: @qdii Fair enough, added your contribution to the answer.

Comment: then I am changing to +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

1. bool const f(...);
2. bool f(...) const ;
3. const bool f(...)  ;

1 and 3 are the same thing, just different order of `const` and `bool`. These two mean that the bool returned is a constant. But since your code is most likely doing something like `bool b = myobject.f();`, the variable `b` is a copy of the value returned by `f()` anyways, so it makes no difference.

2 makes the `this` pointer inside the function `f()` a `const T *this` (where T is your class) - meaning anything in the class is not allowed to be modified. Which is probably what you were asking for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What comes before the name of the function is the return type. The `const` in a type applies to whatever is on the left of it unless there is nothing on the left of it, in which case it applies to whatever is on the right. So the first and third return types are `const` `bool`s, and the second is a non-`const` `bool`. Having a `const` return type means that the value that is returned cannot be modified.

Having `const` after the function arguments list makes the function a `const` function. This only applies to member functions (i.e. declared in a class). A `const` member function can only be called on a `const` object. So if you had a class `foo` with a non-`const` member function `f`, you would not be able to do this:

```
const foo a_foo;
a_foo.f(); // Error because a_foo is const but f is not a const member function
```

So both options 1 and 3 are the same - they are non-`const` functions that return a `const bool` - and option 2 is different - it is a `const` function that returns a `bool`.